# Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported DB Migration

Tags: c#, .net, database-migration

I'm getting this error when I try the migration commands :

> Add-Migration AddAuthentication

> Update-Database

I've added all the proper nugget packages so I don't know where the error stems from.

Here is my startup.cs :

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddDbContext<AuthDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthConnectionString")));

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

And this is my Model :

```
public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }
```

And here is the connection string :

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "AuthConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=AspNetAuth;Trusted_Connection=True"
  }
}
```

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Your connection string is missing the server.  Connect to database using SQL Server Management Studio.  The server name will be in the login window.  Replace the period in the connection string above with the server name shown in SSMS login window.

Comment: I did it but I still get the same error

Comment: Try one of the connection string on following that does not use the parameter SERVER : https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/10/21/net-5-connect-to-sql-server-with-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this connection string for local sql server

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;"
```